# C# web Application - Run a Specific type of Code on Every Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a created a Simple **LOGIN form**...I want to Check **Session["UserId"]** is null or not...on every page load.

Instead of writing on every Page to Check **Session["UserId"]** is null or not.

what is the alternative way to write a common Code and call every page
except **LOGIN and REGISTRATION Form**

if **Session["UserId"]** is null then i can easily Redirect to LOGIN Form
or Else the Code is ongoing

If Possible you can give me Code with example..
Thank You!!

Comment: WebForms or MVC? (While both can use begin request event, the latter would likely be cleaner to use a filter.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code in Global.asax:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{ ...
    void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        // CheckSession() inlined
        if (context.Session["UserId"] == null)
        {
          context.Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you!...but how to avoid to Check on LOGIN and Registration Form

Comment: you can check your url before check session, for example use this `string CurrentURL = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url; `  and set it before check session.

Comment: Your answer is perfect.......thank you...i Forgot to check...

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a class `MyBasePage`, inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page, and put there all (or most) of the common logic shared by all pages in my web application.

When creating a new aspx page, you have to change its declaration so it inherits from `MyPageBase` and not from `Page`

Then `MyBasePage` has a virtual method (or property) `RequiresLogin`, which returns true.
For Login and registration form, you override it returning false.

Finally, in the Load handler for `MyPageBase`, you add something such:

```
if (RequiresLogin && !UserIsAlreadyAuthenticated)
    Response.Redirect ("Login.aspx");
```

You can extend this pattern to handle what you think should be common to all of your pages

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to  mind are attributes. Or better; create your own attribute. Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes Maybe it gives you an idea